# Dropzone in foreach blade laravel not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js

I have  foreach loop of product
products in basket can get many of photos from user
users upload photo to product(sell farm's photo)
modal is in foreach loop

when modal is open dropzone not working and get this error:

dropzone.js:1 Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.

My modal

```
<div class="modal fade"  id="productmultiplephoto-{{$product->pivot->id}}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productmultiplephoto" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header pb-0">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="price-changes-modal-label"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

               <div class="__img">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="hidden" name="original_name[]" id="product-photo">
                       <input name="product_id"  value="{{$product->id}}" type="hidden"  id="product_id" >
                       <input name="product_pivot"  value="{{$product->pivot->id}}" type="hidden"  id="product_pivot" >
                       <input name="cartproduct_id"   type="hidden"  id="cartproduct_id"value="{{$product->pivot->id}}" >

                       <label for="photog">upload</label>
                       <input type="hidden" name="original_name[]" id="product-photo">
                       <div id="photog" class="dropzone" ></div>
                   </div>
               </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My script

```
 <script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var photosGallery = []
    var drop = new Dropzone('#photog', {
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        url: "{{ route('front.photouser.upload') }}",
        type:"POST",

        sending: function(file, xhr, formData){
            formData.append("_token","{{csrf_token()}}")
            formData.append("product_id", document.getElementById('product_id').value);
            formData.append("product_pivot", document.getElementById('product_pivot').value);
            formData.append("cartproduct_id", document.getElementById('cartproduct_id').value);
        },
        success: function(file, response){
            photosGallery.push(response.original_name)
            if (response['level'] == 1) {
                $('.level1_message').html(response['message']);

            }
        }
    });
    productGallery = function(){
        document.getElementById('product-photo').value = photosGallery
    }

</script>
```

My button modal

```
@foreach($cart->products as $product)
     <button  type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productmultiplephoto-{{$product->pivot->id}}" class="btn-primary-multiple btn-primary-cm btn-with-icon">
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus-box-multiple"></i>
        upload
    </button>
   @endforeach
```

Include modal part

```
@include('front::products.partials.add-multiple-photo')
```

Comment: "_modal is in foreach loop_" That makes your code invalid, `id` attributes _must_ be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your div like this :

```
<div class="photog dropzone"></div>
```

for each iteration of the loop, you should also generate a new hidden input element with a unique name attribute for each product so that when uploading the file, you can know to which product the file is being added

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id_{{$product->pivot->id}}" id="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}">
```

Full JS :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var photosGallery = [];
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var dropzones = [];



    let modals = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone-modal');
    modals.forEach((modal, index) => {
        let photog = modal.querySelector('.photog');
        let drop = new Dropzone(photog, {
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            url: "{{ route('front.photouser.upload') }}",
            type: "POST",
            sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("_token", "{{csrf_token()}}")
                let product_id = modal.querySelector(`input[name='product_id']`);
                let product_pivot = modal.querySelector(`input[name='product_pivot']`);
                let cartproduct_id = modal.querySelector(`input[name='cartproduct_id']`);
                formData.append("product_id", product_id.value);
                formData.append("product_pivot", product_pivot.value);
                formData.append("cartproduct_id", cartproduct_id.value);
            },
            success: function(file, response) {
                photosGallery.push(response.original_name)
                if (response['level'] == 1) {
                    $('.level1_message').html(response['message']);
                }
            }
        });
        dropzones.push(drop);
    });

    let modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary-multiple');
    modalButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            dropzones[index].removeAllFiles();
        });
    });


    productGallery = function() {
        document.getElementById('product-photo').value = photosGallery
    }

});
</script>
```

Update your modal div like this :

```
<div class="modal fade dropzone-modal"  id="productmultiplephoto-{{$product->pivot->id}}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productmultiplephoto" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: can you help me to update my script?

Comment: done please check the updated comment

Comment: its just work for one of the modal
another modals get this error: Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.

Comment: Updated answer again: You're initializing the Dropzone object only once, but each loop iteration is binding to the same Dropzone instance, resulting in the error "Dropzone already attached" when the second modal is opened.

Comment: can you  please write complete script? I was a little confused

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'buttons' has already been declared

Comment: I'm assuming you only need the javascript I've updated the code at the bottom

Comment: thanks a lot 
but I get tow error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'modalButtons' has already been declared (at cart:1003:13)


cart:931 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeAllFiles')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart:931:34)

Comment: Updated again for you, please try the js again. If not dump the whole HTML output you have so we can test it properly. Maybe use codepen

Comment: Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.
    at new b (dropzone.js:1:2365)
    at cart:948:24

and also forech works fine and value get correct id
but when upload a photo get  values in database of other modal
correct value not send

Comment: ok updated JS and look at the end for updating your modal with "dropzone-modal" class